# Intermittent CouchDb NoHttpResponseException

Tags: java, couchdb, ubuntu-14.04

When reading a fairly large dataset from CouchDb, using the LightCouch Java API wrapper, intermittent 10 minute hangs occur followed by a NoHttpResponseException and then a retry.

I originally saw it happening on a build of rCouch from GitHub. This occured on multiple machines.

I then moved the data to a vanilla Ubuntu version
"version":"1.5.0","vendor":{"version":"14.04","name":"Ubuntu"}

And it does the same.

All instances run on up-to-date Ubuntu 14.04

On a data set of some 20 million items this typically happen 5 - 10 times,
delaying processing with more than an hour.

Any ideas?

### CouchDb log

```
[Fri, 03 Apr 2015 09:54:16 GMT] [info] [<0.176.0>] 127.0.0.1 - - POST /mydb/_all_docs?include_docs=true 200
[Fri, 03 Apr 2015 10:07:10 GMT] [info] [<0.604.0>] 127.0.0.1 - - GET /mydb/_changes?since=10320000&include_docs=true&limit=40000&feed=normal 200
```

### Application Log

```
2015-04-03 11:54:16,456 INFO main org.lightcouch.CouchDbClient - < Status: 200
2015-04-03 12:07:10,426 INFO main org.lightcouch.CouchDbClient - > GET /mydb/_changes?since=10320000&include_docs=true&limit=40000&feed=normal
2015-04-03 12:07:10,432 INFO main org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec - I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to {}->http://127.0.0.1:5984: The target server failed to respond
2015-04-03 12:07:10,432 INFO main org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec - Retrying request to {}->http://127.0.0.1:5984
2015-04-03 12:07:10,432 INFO main org.lightcouch.CouchDbClient - > GET /mydb/_changes?since=10320000&include_docs=true&limit=40000&feed=normal
2015-04-03 12:07:10,435 INFO main org.lightcouch.CouchDbClient - < Status: 200
```

Comment: Did you store the documents all at once before reading them? If so then this is normal because indexes in couchdb are built when they are read. And the java http client that you are using might have timed out.  If you are inserting many documents at once it might be a good idea to read from the view at frequent intervals so that it is always up to date and does not block.

Comment: No, Zero activity writing to that database. However, in between reading the blocks from the database there are a lot of individual (single record) queries being executed on that same table, on the same connection. Would it help to do these queries on another connection?

Comment: Couchdb should be able to handle multiple connections. But maybe you can try running the operations  via curl to see if the issue is still happening. It could help you  to isolate the problem in either couch or your driver. I don't understand what you mean when you say "zero activity writing to the database" don't you see any logs?

Comment: I mean that at the point where I do this, only read operations occur. ie The data is static.

Comment: Okay what I am saying is this: 1) you add documents to couchdb 2) you read them. At step 2 couchdb creates indexes. This is a slow operation. If you have a lot of documents this will take a lot of time. To reduce this time you should trigger index creation after inserting a certain amount of documents. Divide 20 million into groups of 1 million each (made up the number but you can run some tests to come up with one) and read after each batch of insertion is complete. That will help divide index creation time into smaller chunks.

Comment: I see yes, but our process goes something like: 1) Insert many documents 2) Run our process (read only). ... 3) Run our process again, 4) and again ... 5) and again.  Accessing the same data from couch every time. Surely the indexes would have been created after the 1st run... since it traverses the whole database?

Comment: You are right. If you are reading from the same indices then they are already created. The problem is somewhere else. Unfortunately I don't have a clue to what it could be. Have you tried the mailing list or their irc channel?